# Swift: NSTimer, delay hiding UIButton with each tap

Tags: swift, uibutton, hide, nstimer

I have a button (actually two nearly identical buttons) that unhide with an action in another UIView.

The buttons hide automatically 2 seconds after the panning in the second UIView ends using dispatch_after however I would like to keep the buttons visible if either is tapped while they are visible. Here is the timer property and two methods from the UIButton subclass. I have an @IBAction that calls "justTapped" in the ViewController.

```
var timer = NSTimer()

func hideAndShrink(){
    if !self.hidden && !timer.valid{
        self.hidden = true
    }
}

func justTapped(){
    timer.invalidate()
    timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(2.0, target: self, selector: "hideAndShrink", userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
}
```

Once either button is tapped, they will not hide.

Is the timer still valid while it calls the method in the selector?

**The answer to this, thanks to luk2302, is Yes, the timer is valid when it sends the selector**

How can I get around this?

**As was suggested, I wrote a second method for the timer that hid the buttons without !timer.valid ?**

*It turned out that I did not need the second method at all as I just had any attempt to hide the buttons call justTapped instead. Here is the final code with expand and shrink animations for both buttons. self.direction is the direction I want the button to expand, from the bottom up, or the top down, and also determines the background image. I think it could have been an enumeration but I haven't figured those out yet.*

```
    func unhideAndExpand(){

    if self.hidden{
        expand(self.frame.size.height)
    }

}

func hideAndShrink(){
    if !self.hidden && !shrinking{
        shrink(self.frame.size.height)
    }
}

func justTapped(){
    timer.invalidate()
    timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(3.0, target: self, selector: "hideAndShrink", userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
    }

func expand(height: CGFloat){

    if self.direction == "up"{
        self.transform = CGAffineTransformMake(1, 0, 0, 1/height, 1, height/2)
    } else if self.direction == "down" {
        self.transform = CGAffineTransformMake(1, 0, 0, 1/height, 1, -height/2)
    }
    self.hidden = false
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0, options: .CurveEaseOut, animations:
        {self.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity}, completion: nil)
}

func shrink(height: CGFloat){
    self.shrinking = true
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0, options: .CurveEaseOut, animations:
        {if self.direction == "up"{
            self.transform = CGAffineTransformMake(1, 0, 0, 1/height, 1, height/2)
        } else if self.direction == "down" {
            self.transform = CGAffineTransformMake(1, 0, 0, 1/height, 1, -height/2)
            }
        }, completion: {_ in
            self.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
            self.hidden = true
            self.shrinking = false})
}
```

Thanks everyone for the help.

Comment: Could you clarify what is the issue? What case does not work correctly?

Comment: Didn't know that I could. I hit the check mark on your answer. I hope that's how you accept it?

Comment: @twiz_ if that answer was the most helpful for you, that is the correct way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is the timer still valid while it calls the method in the selector?

## Yes, it is

The following is a complete runnable playground example demonstrating that:

```
import Foundation
import XCPlayground    
XCPSetExecutionShouldContinueIndefinitely()

class Bla {
    var timer : NSTimer?

    init() {
        timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: "check", userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
        
        NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.1, target: self, selector: "checkAgain", userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
    }
    
    @objc func check(){
        print(timer!.valid)
    }
    
    @objc func checkAgain(){
        check()
    }
}

let bla = Bla()
```

This will first output `true` and then output `false`. The timer is still valid *when* firing. As soon as you leave the fired method the timer gets invalidated.

That will render your `if` useless since the method will do nothing when fired by the timer because `anything && !true` evaluates to `false`.

What you can do to circumvent that issue is create a different method `timerFired` which sets some internal property of your class, e.g. `var timerHasFired = false` to `true`. Your `` then has to check that variable instead of the timer:

```
var timer = NSTimer()
var timerHasFired = false

func hideAndShrink(){
    if !self.hidden && hideAndShrink {
        self.hidden = true
    }
}

func timerFired() {
    timerHasFired = true
    hideAndShrink()
}

func justTapped(){
    timer.invalidate()
    timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(2.0, target: self, selector: "timerFired", userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you need `!timer.valid` check? If `hideAndShrink` is called only by timer it seems you can change it to

```
func hideAndShrink(){
    self.hidden = true
}
```

`hideAndShrink` will be called only if timer is not invalidated so you can skip this check.